# Is my redundancy identification and K-Map grouping correct?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

(Problem 7). Am I correct in saying that (m2, m6) the one circled in purple on the k-map is redundant? Also, if that is the case, how do I remove it from the boolean expression? I mean I turned that subcube into it's boolean expression form and got m2 = X'YZ', m6 = XYZ'.

[image]

(Problem 8). Did I do my subcubes wrong cause from the looks of it (4,5,12,13) would be considered unessential, but when I list them out: I don't cover all of the min-terms if I leave it out?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to this site! Generally people here don't do others' homework or verification of others' homework. See this: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7310/238188

Comment: As long as we can see that it was put some efford into solving the task and only specific questions remain it is typically considered OK. I think this is fulfilled here.

Comment: I think this is a valid question. OP has clearly shown us his/her workings and is just asking for some verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use k-map you must consider all the rules.

What you miss is the rule saying that you should have as few groups as possible.

So after covering all 1s you should not add additional groups just because they can fit.

In problem 7, the group (m2,m6) is just one additional group that you do not need. To get the boolean expression of  (m0,m2) for example,  you omit the boolean variable that does not keep its state inside the group which is Y so (m0,m2) is represented by X'Z' and the whole simplified expression will be: X'Z' + XY.

In problem 8, groups (0,1,3,2) , (4,5,12,13) and (15,14,11,10) are enough. But this is not the only solution and your choice is valid. While enumerating all groups you missed (3,2,11,10).

Comment: X'Z' + XY can also be simplified more to z'y(x' + x) which is z'y.

i also realized that there was a shortcut and i didn't need to make a whole truth table :c

Comment: @S.Coughing Why did you multiply by YZ'? Z'Y wont give the same truth table. I am afraid you made a mistake.

Comment: and yes you don't need to fill truth tables you can directly fill the k-map.

Comment: i factored out z' and y, and then used a basic identity i.e. x' + x = 1

Comment: if you don't get the same truth table (same k-map) it means it is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119781/discussion-between-s-coughing-and-paul-ghobril).